# Cannot remove CSS style from element

Tags: css

I'm having trouble removing a shadow being applied to an element.

HTML of element in question

```
<form class="block" method="post" action="poll.php?do=pollvote&pollid=80">
```

I've already changed the form class to something else.

CSS of questionable shadow

```
#sidebar_container .block {
border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 #888888;
padding: 6px;
```

Now the issue with this is, the way Vbulletin has everything worked out is that the same style applies to a ton of elements.. So simply changing it ruins quite a bit of other customizations.

I dont understand why simply changing the "form class" is not working... Checking in firebug, it still holds the regular form class regardless of what changes I make in the template.

For reference: http://www.eldersreach.com/forum.php?styleid=90

It is the Inner box shadow on the "Poll" element in the right corner of the container

Answer (score 0):

This CSS

```
#sidebar_container .block {
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    box-shadow: 0px 0 4px 0 #888;
}
```

is applied to the `<div class="block smaller">...</div>` container. Not the `<form class="block"...</form>` element.

If you want to remove the `box-shadow` property from the container you need to put `box-shadow: none;` in the `#sidebar_container .block {...}` style definition block. Off course this will remove the `box-shadow` from all the `<div>`s with the class `.block`.

My suggestion would be:

1. Add one more class, e.g. `<div class="block smaller noshadow">...</div>` to the element of choice
2. Define one more CSS property after `#sidebar_container .block {...}` in your stylesheet, e.g.

   `#sidebar_container .block {...}`

   `#sidebar_container .noshadow {
       box-shadow: none;
   }`

That should do the job.